# Work easier with list for create playlist of music player android

Tags: java, android

I am new in java and need help to make my Music Player in android. I need best practice to have a playlist like a queue to handle easily for a simple function like next track, last song of album or shuffle play.
I mean is there any concept in android to handle these stuff easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Cursor. It is an Interface which returns the collection of your query data.
The following methods are available in the Cursor interface which iterate through the Cursor, setting the Cursor pointer to the desired position:

- moveToFirst()
- moveToLast()
- moveToNext()
- moveToPrevious()
- moveToPosition(position)

For more info about cursor methods visit this but to create a cursor from list of object you can use MatrixCursor like bellow:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "item", "description" };

MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columns );

 for (JsonElement mus : musics) {
           matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[] { 1, "Item A", "...." });
 }
```

You can find more data from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).